# Resize height of a container div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize

So i'm literally just trying to change the height of a .container classed div with the height of the footer, but i can't seem to get this syntax correct:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var containerHeight = $(".container").height();
var footerHeight = $(".footer").offset().top;
if(footerHeight < containerHeight){
    $('.container').css('height:', (footerHeight.toString()+'px');
}
});
```

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: drop the colon on `height:`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.container').css('height', footerHeight.toString()+'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery's height function:

`$('.container').height(newHeight);`